# How to add remote XYZ source to geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms, xyz

I am new to Geoserver (geoserver.org). I went through tutorials creating new layers. Unfortunately I cannot find a way how to add remote XYZ data source (e.g. t1.openseamap.org/seamark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png). Is it possible?

If not, I understand, that WMS (which should be added as WMS data source) should do the job. It's fine, but I cannot find URL (e.g. OSM one), which would work - probably I am missing parameter part of it - for example I took one from wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WORLD_OSM_WMS, which is http://www.osm-wms.de, but Geoserver says: Error parsing XML.

Comment: Are you trying to add a remote tile service (e.g. OSM) and republish it locally (e.g. as a WMS layer)?

Comment: It isn't clear whether the remote and local are WMS, or the local is WMS but the remote is TMS.

Comment: I am trying to get it remotely - I don't want to copy the tiles on my server (I am afraid it's probably even against licence rules) - and I want to present it locally - so I will be able to combine the raster background layer (the tiles) with my local vector layer. Simply - I want to have my URL like mygeoserver.com?layers=tile_layer,vector_layer ....

Comment: GeoServer supports cascading WMS services but cascading TMS (XYZ) is not supported. Open OSM WMS services tend to die fast probably because they come too popular. That seems to be the case with osm-wms.de and the linked service URLs. You can make WMS layers from XYZ sources with MapServer.